# Trying to add a list of photo credits inDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am working on a book project in InDesign where each chapter is a separate documents, all compiled into a "Book" document. Each chapter has an image on the intro page and these images all come from Flickr Commons. I am aware of the capabilities of Live Caption in generating photo credits, etc. on the fly using image file metadata. However, instead of adding a caption next to each image, I wish to list out all of them separately in a page titled "Photo Credits." Is this possible in InDesign? The list would look something like this:

- *Page 13: Mayan calendar artefacts being sold outside the ancient city of Palenque in Mexico. Source: Justin Vidamo, Mayan Calendar Stamps. 2012, Digital image. Available from: Flickr, https://www.flickr.com/photos/21160499@N04/13998776238 (accessed June 16, 2015).*
- *Page 25: A farmer working in his agave farm. Source: Justin Vidamo, Mayan Calendar Stamps. 2012, Digital image. Available from: Flickr, https://www.flickr.com/photos/21160499@N04/13998776238 (accessed June 16, 2015).*
- *Page 43: Tequila being sold outside of a famous tourist spot in Sonora. Source: Justin Vidamo, Mayan Calendar Stamps. 2012, Digital image. Available from: Flickr, https://www.flickr.com/photos/21160499@N04/13998776238 (accessed June 16, 2015).*

The page number will need to be dynamic if possible. I don't need the complete solution – just a hint of what workflow to use would be enough.

P.S. For what it's worth, I'm working on InDesign CC 2014.

Comment: I don't have an answer but have you looked at [flickr.photos.getExif](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getExif.html) to get the photo exif data? Then do a data merge with InDesign to place the content from an XML file. Not sure about dynamically changing page number based on an image location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Table of Contents for this. For every photo create a textframe with the respective photo credits and put it on the same page as the photo itself (you can of course also use captions for this). You may choose to put these textframes in a seperate layer, to easily hide them. Give these textframes a specific paragraph style (say "photo-credits").
Then create a Table of Contents only including this specific paragraph style.